# Linear function on space of smooth functions, Taylor series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $Q:C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a linear function with the property that if $f(0)=0$ and $f\geq 0$ in a neighborhood of $0$, then $Q(f)\geq 0$. Show that there are constants $c, a_i, b){ij}$, where $1\leq i,j\leq n$ such that $Q(f)=cf(0)+\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(0)a_i+\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(0)b_{ij}$

My attempt: for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, expand $f$ up to third order $f(x)=f(0)+\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(0)x_i+\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(0)x_ix_j+\sum_{i,j,k}\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j\partial x_k}(\zeta)x_ix_jx_k$, where $\zeta$ is some point on the line segment connecting $0$ and $x$. Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ denote the projection onto the ith coordinate. $\pi$ is smooth. Let $Q(\pi_i)=a_i$ and $Q(\pi_i\pi_j)=b_{ij}$. We can write $f=f(0)+\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(0)\pi_i+\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(0)\pi_i\pi_j+\sum_{i,j,k}\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j\partial x_k}(\zeta)\pi_i\pi_j\pi_k$. Using the linearity of of $Q$, we have $Q(f)=cf(0)+\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(0)a_i+\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(0)b_{ij}+\sum_{i,j,k}\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j\partial x_k}(\zeta)Q(\pi_i\pi_j\pi_k)$. Now I'd like to show that $Q(\pi_i\pi_j\pi_k)=0$, but I'm not really seeing how. $\pi_i\pi_j\pi_k(0)=0$, but this function is not positive in any neighborhood of $0$. Could someone please offer some insight? Thank you

Comment: The "Using the linearity of $Q$..." is not right, because $\zeta$ is not a _scalar_! In fact $\zeta$ is a function of $x$...

Comment: Ah yes, good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's curious. I'm going to consider the case $n=1$.

> > **Lemma.** If $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$ then $Q f=0$.

Proof. For $\epsilon>0$ let $$f_\epsilon(x)=f(x)+\epsilon x^2.$$
Taylor's theorem shows that $f(x)=o(x^2)$ as $x\to0$, so for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $f_\epsilon\ge0$ in a neighborhood of the origin. Since $f_\epsilon(0)=0$ this shows that $$Qf_\epsilon\ge0\quad(\epsilon>0).$$

So if $g(x)=x^2$ and $\alpha=Qg$ we have $$Qf+\epsilon\alpha\ge0$$for every $\epsilon>0$, hence $$Qf\ge0.$$

But $-f$ satisfies the same hypothesis, so we also have $$-Qf\ge0,$$hence $Qf=0$.

**Outline** of how the result follows: Say $P$ is the space of polynomials  of degree no larger than $2$. Show that there exist $a,b,c$ so that $$Qp=ap(0)+bp'(0)+cp''(0)\quad(p\in P).$$

Now for every $f$ there exists $p\in P$ with $p(0)=f(0)$, $p'(0)=f'(0)$ and $p''(0)=f''(0)$. The lemma shows that $Qf=Qp$.